# Highchart Bubble does not show the tooltip

Tags: javascript, highcharts

```
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    xAxis: fox.xAxis,
    yAxis: fox.yAxis,
    chart: {
        alignTicks: true,
        type: "bubble",
        backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
        renderTo: chartDiv.attr('id'),
        zoomType: 'xy',
        minRange: 1             
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            turboThreshold: 100000,
            allowPointSelect: true,
            events: ser.plotEvents
        },
        pie: ser.pieOptions,
    },
    tooltip: {
        useHTML: true,
        headerFormat: '<table>',
        pointFormat: '<tr><th colspan="2"><h3>header</h3></th></tr>' +
            '<tr><th>1.kpi:</th><td>111</td></tr>' +
            '<tr><th>2.kpi:</th><td>222</td></tr>' +
            '<tr><th>3.kpi:</th><td>333</td></tr>',
        footerFormat: '</table>',
        borderRadius: 10,
        borderWidth: 3,
        followPointer: true
    },
    series: fox.series
});
```

It does not even show this above without accessing the series values. What am I doing wrong? Edit: here I added the full chart. series include x y and z axises. Using highcharts 4.6.1

Comment: Hi @Thunfische, Could you provide us with a full chart configuration object? Your tooltip options seem to work: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9Lwx7hf5/